# Querying element inside a collection on a json field - Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following json structure on my Postgres. The table is named "customers" and the field that contains the json is named "data"

```
{
  customerId: 1,
  something: "..."
  list: [{ nestedId: 1, attribute: "a" }, { nestedId: 2, attribute: "b" }]
}
```

I'm trying to query all customers that have an element inside the field "list" with nestedId = 1.

I accomplished that poorly trough the query:

`SELECT data FROM customers a, jsonb_array_elements(data->'list') e WHERE (e->'nestedId')::int = 1`

I said poorly because since I'm using jsonb_array_elements on the FROM clausule, it is not used as filter, resulting in a seq scan.

I tried something like:

`SELECT data  FROM customers where data->'list' @> '{"nestedId": 1,  attribute: "a"}'::jsonb`

But it does not return anything. I imagine because the "list" field is seen as an array and not as each type of my records.

Any ideas how to perform that query filtering nestedId on the WHERE condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

`SELECT data  FROM customers where data->'list' @> '[{"nestedId": 1}]';`

This query will work in Postgres 9.4+.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Tho why do i need to put it as an array element? Is it because "list" is an array instead of single object?

Comment: @renanreismartins Yes, because list is an array. Basically, what's happening is, it is returning true if each object in the RHS array is contained in at least one object in the LHS array.